# sizeof("...") in visual c++ makes me unhappy

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sizeof

I was writing a piece of code where I use `sizeof("somestring")` as a parameter of a function, then I noticed the function was not returning the expected value, so I went to see the corresponding asm code and I found an unpleasant surprise. Does anyone have an explanation for this (see the picture)?

[image: Watch window shows sizeof==4, asm 5]

I know there are 1000+ different ways of doing this, I already implemented another one of them, but I do want to know the reason behind this behaviour.

For the curious, this is Visual Studio 2008 SP1.

Comment: In the asm code shown on line 2, it is pushing the offset from the string "PDFA" isn't that the one from the first `memcmp`? Did you copy paste the right asm code? I am sure the same problem occurs, but your image is wrong

Comment: VC10 often makes mistakes when evaluating `sizeof` expressions of pointers and/or references in the watch view. This didn't happened in previous versions. Are you using VC10?

Comment: Aside: `sizeof` is not a "function". Consequently it doesn't "return" anything. `sizeof` is an operator. A sizeof expression evaluates to some particular value.

Comment: `sizeof("data")` is 5 bytes counting final 0 of the array. I suspect the inspector implements it as a function call and converts char literal to pointer to char thus getting answer 4.

Comment: Debugger != compiler.  You get the size of a pointer in the debugger.  There is in general no way for the debugger to know the size of an array.

Comment: @HansPassant: on the other hand, the immediate window, given a complete expression like `sizeof("abcde")`, should give a correct result...

Comment: To check if the debugger is interpreting the string as a pointer, just add an arbitrary number of characters to the string so the length of the string is not ambiguous with the size of a pointer (eg make the string `"pdfa123123"`)

Comment: @yms I mentioned above that the problem was most likely the same. Regardless, when you make posts you should be as clear as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

String literals are of type "array of n `const char`" ([lex.string], ¶8), where n is the number of `char`s of which the string is composed. Since the string is null-terminated, `sizeof` will return the number of "normal" characters plus 1; the watch window is wrong, it's probably a bug (as @Gene Bushuyev said, it's probably interpreting it as a pointer instead of as a literal=array).

The fact that the value 5 is embedded into the code is normal, being `sizeof` a compile-time operator.

Comment: And what about the `4` in the watch window?

Comment: @MooingDuck: probably a bug; I support Gene's idea that it's being interpreted as a pointer (instead of an array), thus giving the result of 4 bytes (32 bit).

Answer (score 11):

The value 5 is correct.  The constant includes the zero terminator byte.  The display of 4 in the watch window is the one that does not appear to be correct.

Answer (score 6):

there is a C-String terminator '\0' on the end of every C-String so "pdfa" is actually the following char array `{'p', 'd', 'f', 'a', '\0'}` but the \0 will not be printed. Use `strlen("pdfa")` instead.

Answer (score 6):

Remember that C strings contain an ending zero `\0`. Five is the correct value.

Answer (score 4):

Well, 5 is the correct value of sizeof("PDFA"). 4 characters + trailing zero.

Also, keep in mind, that "The result does not necessarily correspond to the size calculated by adding the storage requirements of the individual members. The /Zp compiler option and the pack pragma affect alignment boundaries for members."

Speaking of Watch window, I think it is simply shows you the size of the pointer (const char*) itself. Try to recompile program in 64-bit mode and check what Watch window would show then. If I am right, then you will see 8.

Comment: packing does not apply to this, since a string literal is not a struct.

Comment: I prefer to keep the quote from MSDN intact.

Comment: To see if the watch window shows the size of the pointer, just check if `sizeof("pdfa")` and `sizeof("pdfaALSDALSDAS")` have the same value.

Comment: Yeah. That 5 vs 4 characters seems to hit boundary condition where length of the string is sooo similar to size of pointer :)

Answer (score 4):

The reason that Things Go Wrong™ here is that you have chosen a too low level of abstraction, the `memcmp`.

One level up you have `strcmp` and `wcscmp`.

And one level up from that you have `std::string` and `std::wstring`.

The "speed" (hah!) of your chosen lowest level possible abstraction is offset by

- Incorrect result.
- Inefficiency due to lack of type knowledge (wide or narrow string, your code doesn't know).
- Inefficiency due to lack of data knowledge (uppercase or lowercase).

Instead of wasting time on fixing the problems of the inefficient lowest level code, and wasting time on figuring out baffling details of low level tools, use a higher and safer level of abstraction.

---

Just for the record, `sizeof( "abcd" )` is 5. The watch window is probably, as Hans Passant remarked, displaying the size of a pointer. However, I disagree with Hans that the debugger generally has no way to know the size of an array: for a debug build it can know anything and everything about the original source, including the verbatim original source if needed (and it is displaying that verbatim original source, in context). So, that 4 is IMHO a bug one way or the other. Either a bug in the debugger code, or a bug in its design.

Answer (score 2):

Sizeof is a operator that evaluates to a size_t,usually an unsigned int on 32 bit platforms. That is why you see it as 4 in the debugger.  The sizeof operator is also an rvalue, so you cannot set a watch point on the memory.  If you could, the location would contain 5.   The size of your string plus terminator.